# JQuery Open/Close Unique Drawers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, uislider

I am trying to accomplish what may be a simple task for you. I want it so everytime the user clicks one of the "patients" on the left hand bar, a drawer opens. That drawer will be loaded in a hidden div (display:none) on the page. Each div's id will be the last lastname of the patient. My included fiddle shows all of the same last name for demonstration purposes only, obviously.

But the problem is I don't know how to open a unique drawer for each patient. I guess I need to put a toggle on each patient's li somehow?

Also, if they click another patient in the listing, I would like the current open drawer to close, and open the one they just clicked. Also, if the close button is clicked, obviously close the drawer as well.

I got a single drawer to work with this:

```
 $(".patient").toggle(function(){
            $(this)
                $('#drawer').slideDown("slow")

            }, function(){
                $(this)
                $('#drawer').slideUp("slow")    

            });
```

But obviously that isn't going to work... :(

In the fiddle it is opening a standard "drawer" right now. but really I'd like the data for each named div be loaded in the same form. Please comment if you don't understand.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3veht/1/

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you need a unique div for each, why not just dynamically load the content when the user clicks the name?

Comment: @JohnKoerner I would love to be able to dynamically load it! I have tried what I have in my fiddle. Not sure where to even start doing unique items like this, that's why I am asking. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data element to your HTML indicating an ID, let's say patient ID in this case:

```
<li class="patient green" data-patientId="1">Josh Doe<img src="img/next.png"><img class="imgfix" src="img/accept.png"></li>
<li class="patient red" data-patientId="2">John Adams<img src="img/next.png"><img class="imgfix" src="img/cancel.png"></li>
```

Then in your javascript when you load the data, you can use that ID to generate a page request.  I also changed the toggle to a click and slid the previous one up before sliding the new one down.  In the fiddle example:

```
 $(".patient").click(function(){
     var pat = $(this);
     if ($("#drawer").is(":visible"))
         $("#drawer").slideUp("fast", function () {

            $('#drawer').slideDown("slow")
            $("#drawer").load("/echo/js?js=" + pat.data("patientid"));       
         });
     else   
     {
         $('#drawer').slideDown("slow")
         $("#drawer").load("/echo/js?js=" + pat.data("patientid"));
     }
 });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3veht/6/

Comment: @JohnKoemer This is great! Generating a page request may be a bit tougher for me. That is why i wanted to use preloaded hidden div's. Could you add on generating a page request? The data is all php driven

Comment: @JohnKoemer also, it doesn't seem to work properly in the fiddle. Click the first one, then the second, then the first. I would like the drawer to close, then open the one the person just clicked, not reload the open drawer. Would you mind fixing?

Comment: @greycode For the PHP, just replace /echo/js with a URL that returns html.  So you could simply do `$("#drawer").load("details.php?id-=" $(this).data("patientid"));`

Comment: @JohnKoemer gotcha, i just noticed that. Did you notice that the opening doesn't work very well? it didn't work very well from my original fiddle either. Odd

Comment: @greycode see my updated code/fiddle for how to handle the sliding properly.

Comment: Perfect! One more question.. On the live site, I can only toggle the open once and the close once. If I try again, it won't do anything. No errors in console. Any ideas?

Comment: @greycode Not without seeing the code.  If you have a new question, feel free to ask it as a new question, so we don't clutter up this one.

Comment: Thank you. I will link you to the new one in a second. (as a heads up, its the exact same code as in your fiddle now, so nothing is different... No errors in console either, just won't open a second time)

Comment: @JohnKoemer Here's the new one man! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472480/jquery-wont-slide-out-a-second-time

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle updated....

changes made in code

```
 var divud = $(this).text().split(' ')[1];
                $('#drawer').slideDown("slow");
                $('#'+divud).removeClass('hidden');
              $('#'+divud).slideDown("slow");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3veht/3/)